# What's the meaning of "tear off" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I found this sentence describing a motorcycle (The person describing it is very impressed by the motorcycle, finds it very beautiful and magnificent):

> It was mammoth, even at rest it seemed like a street fighter ready for a brawl, as if it wanted to **tear off down the road**, hovering over the asphalt.

I don't understand the meaning of "tear off down the road". How would you paraphrase it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "tear off" is a colloquialism that means to depart with great speed.

> The hot-rod tore off down the street.
>
> She was walking her dog in the park and it tore off after a squirrel.

The verb is **to tear** (which rhymes with "hair", not "beer").  It means "to speed".  **off** means "away".

Comment: It may be helpful to specify which homograph is used in the expression (i.e. the one related to ripping rather than to crying).

Comment: Actually the quoted past tense forms make it clear. Oops.

Comment: That's OK, it can't hurt to add some info.

Comment: Thank you. All these phrasal verbs are a real nightmare for a non-native speaker...